# How to consolidate a Dictionary with multiple (three) keys by reducing one or more key and merging the multiple records (if any) into one single one?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary, key

I have a Dictionary with the following definition.

```
    Dictionary<int[], int> D = new Dictionary<int[], int>();
```

where the key is a 3 element array. I am giving this as example to simplify my scenario. (In my own code the Key is a complex class object that has a List of 3-7 elements in it for key.)

```
    int[] key;
    key = new int[] { 1, 1, 1 };
    D.Add(key, 1);
    key = new int[] { 1, 1, 2 };
    D.Add(key, 2);
    key = new int[] { 1, 1, 3 };
    D.Add(key, 3);
    key = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
    D.Add(key, 4);
    key = new int[] { 2, 1, 1 };
    D.Add(key, 5);
    key = new int[] { 2, 5, 1 };
    D.Add(key, 6);
```

What i want is to have a means to reduce the number of keys, ie. instead of having an array of three element I want a 2 element array as key and have all the values that are redundant be consolidated into one single value so that the resulting KeyValue pairs should look the following way. (reducing the first index for keys)

```
    {1 1, 6} //two instances of matching key of {1 1} resulted the value to have 1+5 =6
    {1 2, 2}
    {1 3, 3}
    {2 4, 4}
    {5 1, 6}
```

Comment: why `1+5` and not `1+2+3`? why `1 2, 2` and not `1 2, 4`? where did `2 4` and `5 1` keys come from? this doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I have taken out the first column from the key list. that leaves me with the second column and third column of the KeyCollection. and if I take only the unique pair from those two columns i get only the 5 keys i posted, and in those 5 only {1 1} has multiple instance at first and fifth element of my original dictionary with value of 1 and 5 respectively. So when i want the dictionary consolidated those two values should get aggregated giving me 1+5=6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your dictionary probably doesn't work as you expect - there is no default comparer for `int[]` type, so keys won't be unique in your dictionary (you can have two elements with `1 1 1` key for example). To get this to work you need to provide custom `IEqualityComparer<int[]>`. This will also be needed to make the solution to your main problem work:

```
public class IntArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
        {        
            return false;
        }

        return x.Zip(y, (v1, v2) => v1 == v2).All(b => b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] x)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So you should create your dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<int[], int> D
    = new Dictionary<int[], int>(new IntArrayEqualityComparer());
```

Returning to the main issue, here is how you can achieve the desired result:

```
var result = D
    .GroupBy(
        kvp => kvp.Key.Skip(1).ToArray(),
        new IntArrayEqualityComparer())
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Sum(x => x.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks, this should give me a base to work with. Appreciate the response.

Any suggestions on how to manage this same with a scenario where the Key is a List<> of objects and if I want to remove any of the columns the List of key tupple?

Comment: @spyronum Basically the same - first of all you must define the equality criterion for both the initial key, and the key with removed column. Conceptually `List<T>` is the same thing as `T[]`.