# Data collection with 3 elements per entry

Tags: c#, collections

Is there a data collection in the .net framework (ideally in `collections.generic` that can deal with three disparate objects (lets say `int`,`string` and `float`) whereby the other two elements can be accessed given one of the elements (assuming every object is unique).

I don't know if this would exist, or even if it could be created, but ideally it would work similarly to a `Dictionary<key,value>` but would in essence be `Collection <key,key,key>` sort of arrangement that could be used like `Collection[key].third = data`.

As I said, I have no idea if this sort of arrangement exists; if it does, could you please point me in the correct direction, if not, could you please let me know if there are any ideas of how this could be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493122/how-to-consolidate-a-dictionary-with-multiple-three-keys-by-reducing-one-or-mo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest data structure out-of-the-box to what you are looking for is `List<Tuple<int, string, float>>`.  You can easily use linq to search for objects that match criteria for any of the three parts.

However, it would not be a significant amount of work to create a custom type that represents your element:

```
public class Element 
{
    public int IntValue {get; set;}
    public string StringValue {get; set;}
    public float FloatValue {get; set;}
}
```

A multi-key dictionary wouldn't be terribly hard, either - just override the indexer for each type.  Note that all three types must be distinct, or you will get compiler errors since the compiler won't know which indexer you are binding to.

The advantage is that you can use *appropriate names* for each value - what does the `int` value represent?  That's one big advantage a custom class has over `Tuple` is *context*.

I would also note that "equality" for `float` values can be tricky.  two float values that *seem* to be equal can in reality be very slightly different.  Floating-point values are often compared by looking within a range for a specified tolerance.  As such they generally make poor keys for indexed structured like `Dictionary`.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you. Could you please expand on what you mean by overriding the indexer? Also, don't worry so much about the types, the given ones were examples as the use case will be GameObject, Coord and Piece, which are non-standard

Comment: I mean add three [indexer overrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) so you can do `collection[GameObject]`, `collection[Coord]`, and `collection[Piece]`.